# Partitioning antidirected trees with bounded degree, such that the graph induced by the partition is a constant antidirected tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, partitions, trees, directed-graphs

Given a partition of the vertices of a graph, we can define an auxiliary graph which conveys information about the edges between sets of the partition. This defines a graph with vertex set equal to the members of the partition and such that there is an edge between a pair of sets iff there's an edge between elements of these sets.

---

**Definition 1:** Let $G$ be a graph, and $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $V(G)$, define the graph $G[\mathcal{P}]$, which has $V(G[\mathcal{P}])=\mathcal{P}$ and $$E(G[\mathcal{P}])=\{UV: U\neq V \in \mathcal{P},\text{ and there exists } u\in U,v\in
V \text{ such that }uv\in E(G)\}.$$

---

This can naturally be extended to directed graphs, in the following sense:

---

**Definition 2:** Let $D$ be a directed graph, and $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $V(D)$, define the graph $D[\mathcal{P}]$, which has $V(D[\mathcal{P}])=\mathcal{P}$ and $$E(D[\mathcal{P}])=\{(U,V): U\neq V \in \mathcal{P},\text{ and there exists } u\in U,v\in
V \text{ such that }(u,v)\in E(D)\}.$$

---

**My question is as follows:**

Let  $T$ be an antidirected tree on $n$ vertices with bounded degree, say $\Delta(T)=\Delta$. For what range of $\gamma \in(0,1)$, does there exist a constant $C$ independant of $\gamma$ and a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $V(T)$ such that the following hold:

1. $\gamma n \leq |U|\leq 2\gamma n$, for all $U\in\mathcal{P}$ (except for at most $C$ such sets which may be smaller),
2. The directed graph $T[\mathcal{P}$] is also an antidirected tree with bounded degree $\Delta'$, independant of $\gamma$,
3. $\mathcal{P}=\mathcal{P^{+}}\cup\mathcal{P}^{-}$, where for all $v\in\mathcal{P}^{+}$, $d^{-}(v)=0$, and for all $v\in\mathcal{P}^{-}$, $d^{+}(v)=0$.

---

**Why do I care about this:**

Suppose I have a tournament $G$ with a $(d,\varepsilon)$-regular partition $(V_{i})_{i=0}^{k}$, it is known that the reduced graph $\mathcal{R}$ associated with this partition roughly preserves the total edge density of the graph, i.e. $|E(\mathcal{R})|\geq(1-2d)\frac{k^2}{2}$.

Burr showed that every digraph $D$ with at least $4(k−1)|V(D)|$ arcs contains all
antidirected trees of order $k$, therefore the reduced graph $\mathcal{R}$ of the tournament $G$ asociated with the partition $(V_{i})_{i=0}^{k}$ contains every antidirected tree of order $\frac{1}{8}(1-2d)k+1$.

The tree $T$ which I mention is the result of contracting pieces of a bigger tree $T'$ which is not antidirected, the main issue is that $T$ is of linear size with respect of the original size $|V(T')|$, and serves as a tool for assignation of these pieces to clusters in the reduced graph for later embedding, but for this i need that the tree which will serve as a proxy for assignation is of size at most $\frac{1}{8}(1-2d)k +1$, this is of constant size with respect to n.

---

Note that this is trivially possible  if $\frac{1}{2n}\leq\gamma\leq\frac{1}{n}$, taking $\mathcal{P}$ to be the partition of singleton sets, and $C=0$, $\Delta'=\Delta$, we have that $T[\mathcal{P}]\cong T.$ Also note that is impossible whenever $\gamma \in(0,\frac{1}{2n})$.

**Proof idea:**

Let $r$ be a fixed root of $T$, and let $(L_i)_{i=0}^{t}$ be the levels of $T$ with respect to $r$, this is $L_{i}=\{v\in V(T):d(r,v)=i\}$, where $d(r,v)$ is the distance to the root, I think this is possible by taking $C=2$ but I'm unsure on how i would prove it, my main idea is to partition "big" levels (of size $\geq\gamma n$), and join "small" consecutive levels of the same parity (this meaning join $L_{1}$ and $L_{3}$ and so forth, until we have in between $\gamma n$ and $2\gamma n$ vertices, preserving parity of levels ensures point 3. of the statement).

Excess vertices of even levels and of odd levels left after finishing will make up the (up to two, hence $C=2$) elements $U_{odd},U_{even}$ of the partition such that $|U_{odd}|,|U_{even}|< \gamma n$.

The **main problem** is to make the partition such that the first part of point 2. stands, this is, that if any given level $L_i$ is big enough to warrant two (or more) sets $U,V\in\mathcal{P}$, they can't have vertices which have neighbours ending up in the same set in the next level, as in the image.

[image: Not useful partition]

Because of this, it might be reasonable to start by the last level, and recursively fill sets of the partition by adding the parents of the last set added, the set of parents of a set is always smaller than the original set, i.e. if $S\subseteq V(T)$, then $|\pi(S)|\leq|S|$, we can even go further as to considering what we could call the 'family' of a set, this is for a set $S\subseteq L_{i}$, the following:

$$f(S):=\{v\in L_{i} : \exists s \in S \text{ such that }\pi(s)=\pi(v)\}.$$

Trivially $|f(S)|\leq \Delta |S|$, and by definition we have that $|\pi\circ f(S)|\leq |S|$, repeating this logic, we have that for every $i\in\{0,...,t\}$ $|(\pi\circ f)^{i}(S)|\leq |S|$.

We can then start by taking a starting set $S\subseteq L_{t}$ of suitable size, and apply $\pi\circ f(S)$, add $S$ to a placeholder set $U_{1}$ in the partition $\mathcal{P}$ which will be filled, and add $\pi\circ f(S)$ to another placeholder set $U_{2}$, then consider $f\circ \pi\circ f (S)$ and join vertices from here to $U_{2}$ until we complete this set or $|U_{2}|$ is of size greater than $\gamma n$.

The next step would be to consider the neighbourhood $N(f\circ \pi\circ f (S),L_{t})$ of vertices in $f\circ \pi\circ f (S)\subseteq L_{t-1}$ that lie in $L_{t}$, this contains $S$ and is invariant under $f$, we would like to add these vertices to the set $U_{1}$ until it's full or we complete this set, also note that $\pi(N(f\circ \pi\circ f (S),L_{t}))\subseteq f\circ \pi\circ f (S)$ which is already saved into some placeholder set of the partition.

On each step we would go one step lower from the lowest visited level, and then explore the vertices not yet visited in outneighbourhoods of following levels. This ensures in a way that we won't have elements of the partition whose out-neighbours lie in the same following set.

---

**Questions**

- ¿Is this idea sound?
- ¿How could i go about writing such a proof, when the details are so messy?
- ¿Is there probably some easier way of obtaining such a partition?
- ¿Is there maybe another extremal result akin to Burr's, that could make it easier embedding antidirected structures that are not necesarilly trees?